# Can I convert Claims Authentication to Classic Mode?

Tags: claims-based-auth, windows-authentication

Is there a way to convert Claims Authentication to Classic?

Also, if I want to start with Windows Authentication and then have the possibility to change to forms Authentication in the future, which authentication type is recommended to use?
And will it be the same URL when switched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switching from claims to classic is possible (as @saumilm describes), but it's not supported and you have to recreate all permissions.

In your comment to @saumilm you mention that you haven't created your webapp yet, wants to start with windows, but have to option to add forms later. In that case you're free to choose, forms is claims, so you can start with classic and switch to claims (which is fully supported) or start of with claims and stay there.

One thing to note is that a few BI features isn't working in claims, which means that on one hand it might be good to start in classic where everything works, on the other hand if you want to be sure you can switch to claims without any problems, then maybe you should start there.

Note that in SP2013 Claims is the default and Classic can't be created from the UI.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can!

You can switch your Authentication Provider between either Claims Based Authentication(CBA) or Classic Authentication, before embarking on changing the authentication provider I would first recommend reading the following technical articles:

- [Migrate from classic-mode to claims-based authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985.aspx)
- [Plan Authentication Method](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx#section2)

More information is in '[SharePoint 2010 Claims to Classic and Classic to Claims](http://www.tsls.co.uk/index.php/2011/02/01/sharepoint-2010-claims-to-classic-and-classic-to-claims/)' article.

Comment: Thanks Saumilim
But if i want to start with Windows Auth and then have the possiblities to change to forms Authentication in the future which authentication type is recommended to use? And will it be the same URL when switched? Thanks in advance

Comment: @PerJakobsen explains your issue wonderfully.

Comment: According to the first bullet, after you migrate a Web application to claims-based authentication, you cannot revert it to classic-mode authentication. (per the first link).

Comment: @QuinnJohns Agree. Reverting to older Auth is tricky.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion from SharePoint 2013 web application utilizing claims based authentication back to windows classic auth is not supported.  Windows classic web application can only be created as new web application (New-SPWebApplication) or migrated from SharePoint 2010 Windows Classic -> SharePoint 2013 Windows Classic